# How to unset a property on a Delta object

Tags: c#, odata, azure-mobile-services, delta

I am using Azure Mobile App Services and in the PATCH method I receive as body an object of type Delta (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890572%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

I receive some fields with null values that I would like to remove from the Delta input object: how can I do this action?

e.g. I have a JSON input like

```
{
    "Content":"test",
    "CreatedAt":null
    ...
}
```

this maps an Entity that inherits from Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.EntityData
e.g.

```
public class MyBean : EntityData
{
    public MyBean() { }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to remove the field "CreatedAt", which by the way is declared in the EntityData parent object, part of the Microsoft library (therefore I don't have direct access to it).

Comment: What is the type of your input? Is it a string? Some deserialized object?

Comment: Thanks @EvanTrimboli, I just edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should try to remove the CreatedAt, but instead, take the incoming Delta and create a new one.  You could either include the fields you wanted or exclude the ones you don't want.

```
var newDelta = new Delta<MyBean>();
foreach(var fieldName in patchDelta.GetChangedPropertyNames()){
  if(fieldName != "CreatedAt"){
    if(patchDelta.TryGetPropertyValue(fieldName, out object fieldValue)){
      newDelta.TrySetPropertyValue(fieldNAme,fieldValue);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, do you have any clue about the performance? I have beans with 20 fields more or less, out of which usually 5 are immutable (which means I want to remove from the Delta).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Delta<T> class and any overhead as part of the Azure Mobile App Services, but I'd expect performance concerns to be negligible.  It's some more heap allocations, but the work is going to be a small percentage of all the other things going on the in the request, like authorization, deserialization, etc etc.  If you were unsure of the Type in such a way that the TryGets and TrySets were going to fail occasionally you might get some performance hiccups, but since these are known types with known field names those should never return false and should hum along just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Newtonsoft.Json to serialize the Entity then you can use [conditional serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) of a property.

> To conditionally serialize a property, add a method that returns
>   boolean with the same name as the property and then prefix the method
>   name with ShouldSerialize. The result of the method determines whether
>   the property is serialized. If the method returns true then the
>   property will be serialized, if it returns false then the property
>   will be skipped.

```
public class MyBean : EntityData
{
    public MyBean() { }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCreatedAt()
    {        
        return false;
        // Or you can add some condition to whether serialize the property or not on runtime 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinit this is encouraging, but I have few problems with this approach: first is I need to add biz logic in DE-serialization, not in serialization; second, how can I apply some business logic inside the method, e.g. to allow the de-serialization for POST methods and not for PATCH methods; third, my question is more related to the management of Delta objects, rather than JSON massaging.